# Sorting Collections of Objects within another collection of Objects

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

First I have 2 classes

```
class Student
{
    int StudentID
    string Name
    Fee fee
}
class Fees
{
    int FeeID
    string FeeName
    DateTime FeeDueDate
}
```

let say there are 10 students objects Student[] stud = new Student[10]

and if stud[0] has 4 fees ( Fee[4] ) and they are

```
FeeID=1, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate="2014/06/25"
FeeID=2, FeeName="Tuition", FeeDueDate="2013/03/21"
FeeID=3, FeeName="Sports Equipment", FeeDueDate="2013/03/18"
FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate="2013/07/26"
```

while stud[1] has 2 fees ( Fee[2] ) and they are

```
FeeID=2, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate="2014/06/20"
FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate="2013/03/26"
```

and stud[2] has ......

I need the sort the second collection which is the Fee by FeeDueDate asscending while Keep the same order of student

so after sorting would be

```
stud[0] =>

FeeID=3, FeeName="Sports Equipment", FeeDueDate="2013/03/18"
FeeID=2, FeeName="Tuition", FeeDueDate="2013/03/21"
FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate="2013/07/26"
FeeID=1, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate="2014/06/25"

stud[1] =>

FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate="2013/03/26"
FeeID=2, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate="2014/06/20"
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Also this image shows my collections of objects
http://oi50.tinypic.com/wuq9o3.jpg

Comment: Does each student have a collection of `Fees`'s? Also [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: that completely depends, how your field fee is implemented in your first class. it is a list, is it a database object?

Comment: i tried: objStudentWithFeeData = objStudentWithFeeData.OrderBy(stu => stu.Fees.DueDate).ToList(); but it seems it cant find the DueDate in stu.Fees The Student/Fee class is implemented on the WCF service end. I have no access to it

Comment: actually you shouldnt get your schoolwork done by asking on stackoverflow no matter how tempting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this would solve your 2nd Problem. Try hard to understand it... or your teacher will know the answer is not your own...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var students = new[] {
                new Student()   
                    { StudentID = 0, Name = "Mark", fees =
                        new List<Fee>() {
                            new Fee() { FeeID=1, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2014,06,25), FeeAmount = 1.30 },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=2, FeeName="Tuition", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,21), FeeAmount = .30 },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=3, FeeName="Sports Equipment", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,18), FeeAmount = .80 },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,07,26), FeeAmount = 0}
                        }
                    },
                new Student()
                    { StudentID = 1, Name = "Tom", fees =
                        new List<Fee>() {
                            new Fee() { FeeID=2, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2014,06,20), FeeAmount = 1.50 },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,26), FeeAmount = 4.00 }
                        }
                    }
                };

            var sorted = (from student in students
                         select new
                         {
                             stud = student.StudentID,
                             name = student.Name,
                             feesum = student.fees.Sum(x => x.FeeAmount),
                             fees =
                                 from fee in student.fees
                                 orderby fee.FeeDueDate ascending
                                 select fee
                         }).OrderByDescending(s => s.feesum);

            foreach (var item in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("stud[{0}] => {1}, Fees: {2}", item.stud, item.name, item.feesum);
                foreach (var f in item.fees)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }


    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public List<Fee> fees {get; set;}
    }

    public class Fee
    {
        public int FeeID {get; set;}
        public string FeeName {get; set;}
        public DateTime FeeDueDate { get; set; }
        public double FeeAmount { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
             return String.Format("FeeID={0,2}, FeeName={1,20}, FeeDueDate={2}", FeeID, FeeName, FeeDueDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you classes look like this:

```
   public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public List<Fee> Fees {get;set;}
    }

    public class Fee
    {
        public int FeeID { get; set;}
        public string FeeName { get; set;}
        public DateTime FeeDueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

You could do it like this:

```
        Student[] studs = new Student[10]

        //somehow fill the array

        foreach (var student in studs)
        {
            student.Fees = student.Fees.OrderBy(c => c.FeeDueDate).ToList()
        }
```

**EDIT**
To make sure the the `Fees` list is not null, you could initialize it like this:

```
   public class Student
   {
       public Student()
       {
         Fees = new List<Fees>();
       }

        public int StudentID { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public List<Fee> Fees {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried your way but there is an error with student.Fees.OrderByDescending(c => c.DueDate).ToList();  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StudentList.RServiceReference.Fee>' to 'StudentList.RServiceReference.Fee[]

Comment: @user1618180 I have updated the answer - it should not be `OrderBy Desending`, just `OrderBy`. Check that a studens list of `Fees` is not null. you cound init. it in the `Stundent` constructor. See edit

Comment: Lol, always nice to alt-tab back and see the EXACT SAME solution :). +1 nonetheless :)

Comment: Sorry, still given me error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StudentList.RServiceReference.Fee>' to 'StudentList.RServiceReference.Fee[]'

Comment: @user1618180 replace `.ToList()` with `.ToArray()` my example assumes that `Fees` is a list - not an array :)

Comment: @JensKloster Ah lets gold plate it then :p : `students.ForEach(student => student.Fees = student.Fees.OrderBy(fee => fee.FeeDueDate).ToList());`

Comment: thanks Jens!!!! Had trouble with this school assignment. Already spent 2 hours on it

Comment: I was wondering if Jens can help me on another thing related to this question

Comment: let say in the Fee has another property, FeeAmount now I need to sort again by student (sort the order of student collect) with highest amount of FeeAmount my email is d87c@live.ca maybe we can have conversation there

Comment: @user1618180 sry but I dont have the time right now:/ but you should check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) out. It shows how to `.OrderBy().ThenBy()` if you need to sort on multiple properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var students = new[] {
                new Student()   
                    { StudentID = 0, Name = "Mark", fees =
                        new List<Fee>() {
                            new Fee() { FeeID=1, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2014,06,25) },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=2, FeeName="Tuition", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,21) },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=3, FeeName="Sports Equipment", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,18) },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,07,26)}
                        }
                    },
                new Student()
                    { StudentID = 1, Name = "Tom", fees =
                        new List<Fee>() {
                            new Fee() { FeeID=2, FeeName="Books", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2014,06,20) },
                            new Fee() { FeeID=4, FeeName="School Dorm", FeeDueDate=new DateTime(2013,03,26) }
                        }
                    }
                };

            var sorted = from student in students
                         orderby student.StudentID
                         select new
                         {
                             stud = student.StudentID,
                             fees =
                                 from fee in student.fees
                                 orderby fee.FeeDueDate ascending
                                 select fee
                         };

            foreach (var item in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("stud[{0}] => ", item.stud);
                foreach (var f in item.fees)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }


    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public List<Fee> fees {get; set;}
    }

    public class Fee
    {
        public int FeeID {get; set;}
        public string FeeName {get; set;}
        public DateTime FeeDueDate { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
             return String.Format("FeeID={0,2}, FeeName={1,20}, FeeDueDate={2}", FeeID, FeeName, FeeDueDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well its a copy of my whole Program.cs of a console app. As always I seem to be too slow :-) have fun anyway

Comment: Thanks Ingo!, stackoverflow is full of awesome knowledgable people

Comment: let say in the Fee has another property, FeeAmount now I need to sort again by student with highest amount of FeeAmount my email is d87c@live.ca maybe we can have conversation there

Comment: just replace `orderby fee.FeeDueDate ascending` by `orderby fee.FeeAmount ascending` ... if you want to create a method where you can pass the property Name after which the sorting shall be done, I would probably use a linq Expression like Jens did, and pass the property as a Lambda to the method so inside the method you can place the Lambda as you got it into the linq expressions `.OrderBy( Lambda ).` .. oh and then you would Need to Aggregate the sum of the amount field to the student